# cannot quit with Nano using CTRL + X in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, docker

I have a simple problem while installing Docker in Ubuntu-16.04 terminal. I have opened the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (using nano)

[see image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERsOY.png) I couldn't quit the file when typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. I have attempted many times but no result.

Comment: This kind of looks like VIM. Nano has a bar along the bottom. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-vim-save-and-quit-command/ Vim uses the wild `:` key.

Comment: In general, questions about using OS-provided tools (as opposed to developing software) should be asked at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [unix.se]. Programmer's editors -- such as vim or emacs -- have a stronger claim to topicality here, but nano is not onesuch.